# MySQL update Loop -> how to

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates

I want to loop the following command, for all distinct values in a column

```
update myTable set myUglyField = replace(myUglyField,'<trimmed distinct value here>\r\n','<trimmed distinc value here>');
```

Anyone know if this could be done, instead of going one by one to remove \r\n

Comment: why not just `update myTable set myUglyField = replace(myUglyField,'\r\n','');`?

Comment: I was afraid that would replace all data in the column and not just the \r\n

Comment: Take the back of table before doing any update. Run the above query if you want to only remove the `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run that query you have right there it will update ALL rows in the table, so I think you're good.

Comment: 'update myTable set myUglyField = replace(myUglyField,'\r\n','');' I dont want it to replace any data in there just remove the \r\n, that would work just like that?

Comment: @Kris Yes, please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have all replacements in a table (3 columns, in which value, what to replace and the replacement), you can write:

```
update myTable join replacements on myTable.myUglyFied = replacements.in_value
set myUglyField = replace(myUglyField, replacements.what_to_replace, replacements.replacement)
```